# Why is this vector implementation more performant?

Tags: c++, performance

For learning purposes, I decided to implement my own vector data structure. I called it list because that seems to generally be the more proper name for it but that's unimportant.

I am halfway through implementing this class (inserting and getting are complete) and I decide to write some benchmarks with surprising results.

My compiler is whatever Visual Studio 2019 uses. I have tried debug and release, in x64 and x86.

For some reason, my implementation is faster than vector and I cannot think of a reason why. I fear that either my implementation or testing method are flawed.

Here are my results (x64, debug):

```
List: 13269ms
Vector: 78515ms
```

Release has a much less drastic, but still apparent, difference.

```
List: 65ms
Vector: 247ms
```

Here is my code

dataset.hpp:

```
#ifndef DATASET_H
#define DATASET_H

#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

namespace Dataset {
    template <class T>
    class List {
    public:
        List();
        List(unsigned int);
        void push(T);
        T& get(int);
        void reserve(int);
        void shrink();
        int count();
        int capacity();
        ~List();
    private:
        void checkCapacity(int);
        void setCapacity(int);
        char* buffer;
        int mCount, mCapacity;
    };


    template <class T>
    List<T>::List() {
        mCount = 0;
        mCapacity = 0;
        buffer = 0;
        setCapacity(64);
    }
    template <class T>
    List<T>::List(unsigned int initcap) {
        mCount = 0;
        buffer = 0;
        setCapacity(initcap);
    }
    template <class T>
    void List<T>::push(T item) {
        checkCapacity(1);
        new(buffer + (sizeof(T) * mCount++)) T(item);
    }
    template <class T>
    T& List<T>::get(int index) {
        return *((T*)(buffer + (sizeof(T) * index)));
    }
    template <class T>
    void List<T>::reserve(int desired) {
        if (desired > mCapacity) {
            setCapacity(desired);
        }
    }
    template <class T>
    void List<T>::shrink() {
        if (mCapacity > mCount) {
            setCapacity(mCount);
        }
    }
    template <class T>
    int List<T>::count() {
        return mCount;
    }
    template <class T>
    int List<T>::capacity() {
        return mCapacity;
    }
    template <class T>
    void List<T>::checkCapacity(int cap) {
        // Can <cap> more items fit in the list? If not, expand!
        if (mCount + cap > mCapacity) {
            setCapacity((int)((float)mCapacity * 1.5));
        }
    }
    template <class T>
    void List<T>::setCapacity(int cap) {
        mCapacity = cap;
        // Does buffer exist yet?
        if (!buffer) {
            // Allocate a new buffer
            buffer = new char[sizeof(T) * cap];
        }
        else {
            // Reallocate the old buffer
            char* newBuffer = new char[sizeof(T) * cap];
            if (newBuffer) {
                std::copy(buffer, buffer + (sizeof(T) * mCount), newBuffer);
                delete[] buffer;
                buffer = newBuffer;
            }
            else {
                throw std::runtime_error("Allocation failed");
            }
        }
    }
    template <class T>
    List<T>::~List() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mCount; i++) {
            get(i).~T();
        }
        delete[] buffer;
    }

    long benchmark(std::function<void()>);
    long benchmark(std::function<void()>, long);

    long benchmark(std::function<void()> f) {
        return benchmark(f, 100000);
    }

    long benchmark(std::function<void()> f, long iters) {
        using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
        using std::chrono::duration_cast;
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (long i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
            f();
        }
        auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto time = duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
        return (long)time.count();
    }

}


#endif
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "dataset.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


/*

    TEST CODE

*/


class SimpleClass {
public:
    SimpleClass();
    SimpleClass(int);
    SimpleClass(const SimpleClass&);
    void sayHello();
    ~SimpleClass();
private:
    int data;
};

SimpleClass::SimpleClass() {
    //std::cout << "Constructed " << this << std::endl;
    data = 0;
}

SimpleClass::SimpleClass(int data) {
    //std::cout << "Constructed " << this << std::endl;
    this->data = data;
}

SimpleClass::SimpleClass(const SimpleClass& other) {
    //std::cout << "Copied to " << this << std::endl;
    data = other.data;
}

SimpleClass::~SimpleClass() {
    //std::cout << "Deconstructed " << this << std::endl;
}

void SimpleClass::sayHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello! I am #" << data << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    long list = Dataset::benchmark([]() {
        Dataset::List<SimpleClass> list = Dataset::List<SimpleClass>(1000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            list.push(SimpleClass(i));
        }
    });

    long vec = Dataset::benchmark([]() {
        std::vector<SimpleClass> list = std::vector<SimpleClass>(1000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            list.emplace_back(SimpleClass(i));
        }
    });

    std::cout << "List: " << list << "ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector: " << vec << "ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Here are my results (x64, debug):` -- It's meaningless to time debug builds.   Time the release, optimized builds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I also included release results

Comment: My point is that it isn't really relevant to show debug build timing info.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was unaware.

Comment: From looking at your code, it violates the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  Where is the copy constructor and assignment operator for `List`?  You are making copies, but it is bug-ridden due to the lack of these functions.  Lines like this: `Dataset::List<SimpleClass> list = Dataset::List<SimpleClass>(1000);` -- is not correct, since `List` does not have correct copy semantics.

Comment: `std::copy(buffer, buffer + (sizeof(T) * mCount), newBuffer);` is going to cause undefined behavior for all but trivially copyable types (which your example element type is not.).  Also, your char buffer doesn't take into account alignment so on some systems your code may just crash.  Your `get` function is also illegal without `std::luander`.  Until the code is standard conforming, the benchmark is pointless.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought only construction and deconstruction happen for list in this implementation, I don't see where it is copied

Comment: vector will grow in factor of two when push_back, this is really cost time to allocate new memory. I think the way you implement is not grow in factor of two.

Comment: @Steven both pre-allocate 1000, neither is growing

Comment: @AlgoRythm -- Look at the line of code I highlighted in my previous comment.  What does that do?  And you haven't addressed the point of not having correct copy semantics.  How do you know there isn't a copy going on somewhere, where your class will silently fall apart?  Why didn't you `= delete` those operations, to ensure this?

Comment: `std::vector<SimpleClass>(1000)` isn't "pre-allocation", it constructs a vector with 1000 elements. You then add another 1000 elements in your loop.

Comment: I think @Blastfurnace hit the nail on the head, but it would be nice if I got some answers rather than comments ;)

Comment: I would expect a const reference as a parameter for the push function, and there is a misuse of vector::emplace_back, which expects the parameters to a SimpleClass constructor.  Have you tried comparring your push function to vector::push ? Comparing apples to apples is important here.  Your misuse of vector::emplace_back may create an unnecessary copy.   Looking at the assembly code will help you find out what is really going on.  Use an online compiler, something like godbolt.org.

The discrepancy is probably due to something happening before the jump to push/emplace_back is actually made.

Comment: @NathanOliver The use of std::launder is not necessary, its use here would be pointless. It may be illegal not to use it in your state, but for most locations, the get function is fine as is. – Michaël Roy 9

Comment: @MichaëlRoy They are copying a char buffer, not an object buffer.  That's what `memcpy` does.  `memcpy` requires trvial copyable and so does this since it does the same thing.  Imagine if the OP's vector held a `std::string`.  This copy operation would do a shallow copy and then you have UB.

Comment: Also, you might thing that not using `std::launder` is okay, but it isn't, it's why it was made, to fill a hole in the language.  Just because sane compilers do the sane thing doesn't mean a compiler would be wrong to do whatever it wanted.

Comment: Irrelevant to question, but creating a `List` with capacity 0 and adding an item results in writing to unallocated memory, likewise for a `List` with capacity 1 and adding two items.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) with one parameter creates vector with count elements:

```
explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

To have something comparable for vector you have to do:

```
std::vector<SimpleClass> list;
list.reserve( 1000 );
```

also your "vector" copies objects it holds by simply copying memory, which is only allowed for trivially copyable objects, and `SimpleClass` is not one of them as it has user defined constuctors.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211849/discussion-on-answer-by-slava-why-is-this-vector-implementation-more-performant).

Answer (score 1):

This is a really nice start!  Clean and simple solution to the exercise.  Sadly, your instincts are right that you weren’t testing enough cases.

One thing that jumps out at me is that you never resize your vectors, and therefore don’t measure how most STL implementations can often avoid copying when they grow in size.  It also never returns any memory to the heap when it shrinks.  You also don’t say whether you were compiling with `/Oz` to enable optimizations.  But my guess is that there’s a small amount of overhead in Microsoft’s implementation, and it would pay off in other tests (especially an array of non-trivially-copyable data that needs to be resized, or a series of vectors that start out big but can be filtered and shrunk, or storing lots of data that can be moved instead of copied).

One bug that jumps out at me is that you call `new[]` to allocate a buffer of `char`—which is not guaranteed to meet the alignment requirements of T.  On some CPUs, that can crash the program.

Another is that you use `std::copy` with an uninitialized area of memory as the destination in `List::setCapacity`.  That doesn’t work except in special cases: `std::copy` expects a validly-initialized object that can be assigned to.  For any type where assignment is a non-trivial operation, this will fail when the program tries to call a destructor on garbage data.  If that happens to work, the move will then inefficiently clone the data and destroy the original, rather than using the move constructor if one exists.  The STL algorithm you really want here is `std::uninitialized_move`.  You might also want to use `calloc`/`realloc`, which allows resizing blocks.

Your capacity and size members should be `size_t` rather than `int`.  This not only limits the size to less memory than most implementations can address, calculating a size greater than `INT_MAX` (i.e., 2 GiB or more on most implementations) causes undefined behavior.

One thing `List::push` has going for it is that it uses the semantics of `std::vector::emplace_back` (which you realize, and use as your comparison).  It could, however, be improved.  You pass `item` in by value, rather than by const reference.  This creates an unnecessary copy of the data.  Fortunately, if `T` has a move constructor, the extra copy can be moved, and if `item` is an xvalue, the compiler might be able to optimize the copy away, but it would be better to have `List::push(const T&)` and `List::push(T&&)`.  This will let the class push an xvalue without making any copies at all.

`List::get` is better, and avoids making copies, but it does not have a `const` version, so a `const List<T>` cannot do anything.  It also does not check bounds.

Consider putting the code to look up the position of an index within the buffer into a private inline member function, which would drastically cut down the amount of work you will need to do to fix design changes (such as the ones you will need to fix the data-alignment bug).